# Do you need to pass both the workbook and worksheet to sub/function

Tags: excel, vba

If you are going to be just working with a single worksheet in your function or sub and you pass the worksheet, do you also need to pass the workbook, or does that come along with worksheet that was passed?

Option 1

```
Sub option1 (byref wb as workbook, byref ws as worksheet)

     wb.ws.range("A1") = 8

end sub
```

Option 2

```
sub option2(byref ws as worksheet)

     ws.range("A1") = 8

end sub
```

in option 2 is there any danger of of opening a worksheet with the same name in a different workbook then then the one you passed the worksheet from?

Comment: Option 2....... Side note, use `ByVal`.

Comment: Just pass the range to your function/sub.  the range object has a worksheet method , and the worksheet has a workbook method and so on.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you for the byval comment  still getting in the habit of using them.  the terminology in my head is still global and local variable and I mix up which is which.  One day I will even remember (hopefully) which is best to use in each situation.

Comment: 99.999999% of the time you want `ByVal`.

Comment: Option 1 won't work, since `Workbook` object doesn't have `.ws` property or method.

Comment: @BigBen is it considered bad form to send variable to a sub, have it as byref in the sub declaration, then proceed to give it a value in the sub so that the value can then be used when the sub is complete?  Assuming the sub is doing a bunch of other things.

Comment: Not necessarily. I should also clarify that arrays are passed `ByRef`.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you!  I recall I tried to pass a a few things by val and got errors stating I had to use byref.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The worksheetobject always has a workbook as a parent. So as long as you make sure you're calling the right worksheet when passing it on, you should be fine. So something like this should always work:

```
dim ws as Worksheet

set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

call option2(ws)
```

Comment: That is what I thought, but I wanted to verify.  The same concept applies to a range which will have a worksheet parent which, will also have a workbook parent.